# weblogic 12cR2. How to add library before run config.sh

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, driver, config

This is maybe not an issue for who knows how config.sh work when you config weblogic after you installed it into your disk.

My question is: After I installed weblogic 12cR2. How I can add a customer JDBC driver jar file into weblogic 12cR2 before I run config.sh as when I do config, system need use it to connect my database?

I tried to put it in:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/db2jcc4.jar
```

and then, I add the full driver jar file path into java class path with this file:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/commExtEnv.sh
```

Then I restart my Mac and then, redo config.sh to set up component datasource (em module need it) for RCU. Weblogic blaming driver not found.

but, if I start weblogic server by using $DOMAINH_HOME/startWebLogic.sh. weblogic can find that driver in the path.

What's wrong I did? Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change "commExtEnv.sh". In Weblogic 12c you can create a file called "setUserOverrides.sh" in order to customize the Weblogic starting paramters like the classpath. In your case you could have something like this:

```
# add custom libraries to the WebLogic Server system classpath
if [ "${POST_CLASSPATH}" != "" ] ; then
  POST_CLASSPATH="${POST_CLASSPATH}${CLASSPATHSEP}$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/db2jcc4.jar"
  export POST_CLASSPATH
else
  POST_CLASSPATH="$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/db2jcc4.jar"
  export POST_CLASSPATH
fi
```

The "setUserOverrides.sh" must be placed in the bin folder of your domain, where setDomainEnv.sh, setStartupEnv.sh and startWebLogic.sh reside.

You can find more information here in the Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/START/overview.htm#START250

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try it today some time to see what's going on. Cidy